# Is the site answers.opencv.org down since few days ago?

Tags: opencv, web

I am from Argentina, the site answers.opencv.org seems to be down.

Answer (score 1):

the following link says "there is error in hosting and may be hardware error in in the hosting machine the are working to fix the problem"
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/6499

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://answers.opencv.org/ , 
http://www.websitedown.info/answers.opencv.org, and http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/answers.opencv.org.html -

Yes, http://answers.opencv.org appears to be down.

Edit: It seems to be back up now.